# YII2 UrlManager wrong route

Tags: module, yii2, yii-url-manager

On my site I have this urlManager rule:
`'city/<id:\d+>-<alias:\S*>' => 'city/view'`,
On page of module "user", for example this https://example.com/user/profile, there is a link for rule

```
Url::to(['city/view', 'id' => $this->id, 'alias' => $this->alias], $absolute)
```

But link becomes this https://example.com/user/city/view?id=1&alias=city_alias
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add module ID in the route as well. In the simplest case it's

```
'user/city/<id:\d+>-<alias:\S*>' => 'user/city/view'
```

If there are more than one module using similar route you can use wildcard

```
'<module>/city/<id:\d+>-<alias:\S*>' => '<module>/city/view'
```

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear. I have common layout that it visible on all pages of my site. In it, I have link Url::to(['city/view', 'id' => $this->id, 'alias' => $this->alias], $absolute). But inside module this route doesn't work

Comment: Yes, because routing always assume `<module>/<controller>/<action>` structure - if there is no `<module>` given the current one is used. Adding `$absolute` parameter does not change it, it's only creating full URL with `http://`, base URL and so on. You can always start route with `/` which means that base module (main app) should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply try :

```
Url::to(['/city/view', 'id' => $this->id, 'alias' => $this->alias], $absolute)
```

Read more about [creating urls](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#creating-urls).

Comment: Url::to(['city/view', 'id' => $this->id, 'alias' => $this->alias], $absolute) is defined in common layout, that is visible on all pages of site. So this route is global, not only for module. But in module route becomes /user/city/view and return 404 error.